# I need a htaccess rule, if a url contains question mark after main domain

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I need a htaccess rule, if a url contains question mark after main domain

for example:

http://example.com/?

or

http://example.com/?xyz

it should be redirected to  home / index page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in root/.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*$
RewriteRule ^/?$ /? [NC,L,R]
```

Empty question mark at the end of target path is importent as it discard the orignal querystrings, in apache 2.4 and later you can use **QSD** Flag to discard query strings.

If the rule above fails, then try

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /\?([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ /? [NC,L,R]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, where should i place my url in above rules?

Comment: thanks you so much for the great help! it works as i was looking for... love it.